# Unable to import numbered Streamlit pages as modules

Tags: python, python-import, streamlit

I've a multi-page Streamlit application in the following structure:

```
src\project
  | Home.py
  | pages\
      | 1_abc.py
      | 2_def.py
      | 3_ghi.py
tests
  | test_app.py
```

Streamlit is able to launch and load these pages correctly. However, I'm having issues trying to import these pages as modules for unit testing:

```py
# test_app.py
from project.Home import HomeClass
from project.pages.1_abc import ABCClass
from project.pages.2_def import DEFClass
from project.pages.3_ghi import GHIClass

# ...
```

The above returns `SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal`

I figured out that `1_abc` etc. is an invalid name format for modules as module names cannot start with a number, but that number is used by Streamlit to control the ordering of pages in the sidebar. It seems to me that importing a file as a module is mutually exclusive with loading the file as a Streamlit page in a controlled sequence.

Is there any way to reconcile the 2 requirements? For example, can I define the page order elsewhere, for example in a configuration file for Streamlit to reference? Or can I define the module name elsewhere for Python to use as an alternative to filename?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to circumvent this is to put a underscore in front of the number, like this:

```
src\project
  | Home.py
  | pages\
      | _1_abc.py
      | _2_def.py
      | _3_ghi.py
tests
  | test_app.py
```

The order is respected, the imports are possible. The only downside is that the number appears inside the sidebar..

[image: sidebar with pages titles. The numbers appear]

---

Note: There are currently some issues open on the Streamlit GitHub about the naming of the files in multi-pages apps. For example, this one: https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/5656. To see the open issues about multi-pages apps, you can go [here](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20sort%3Aupdated-desc%20label%3Afeature%3Amultipage-apps). Also, you can try opening your own issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

After experimenting around, I did this in `src/project/pages/__init__.py`:

```py
from importlib import import_module

ABCClass = import_module("project.pages.1_abc").ABCClass
DEFClass = import_module("project.pages.2_def").DEFClass
GHIClass = import_module("project.pages.3_ghi").GHIClass
```

Then this in `tests/test_app.py`:

```py
from project.Home import HomeClass
from project.pages import (
    ABCClass,
    DEFClass,
    GHIClass,
)


# ...
```

Not ideal imo, but it works.